# "show as popover" is not coming while dragging from one view controller to another view controller in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I want to show a popover in my iPad app. but while dragging from one view controller to another in `Xcode 8`. it is giving me only three options segue ,modal and custom.

It is not showing `show as popover`.

I have attached image url for my problem.

What should i do?

[image]

Comment: image url is given https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOHqr.png

Comment: code formatted, display image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using "Size classes"

So goto your Storyboard select any ViewController and then goto right side window select "Show the File Inspector" option in which check checkboxes named:
* Use AutoLayout
* Use Size Classes

like this screenshot

[image]